# MongoDB search with colon in field name

Tags: mongodb, aem

Below is a structure of Mongo entry I have that needs to come up in search

```
{ 
"_id" : BinData(0, "lAAXAUCdQp2sBJH7gbGaEku2Lt07G90MXQ7OsfMmRw+UGQ=="),  
"subdata" : {
    "abcd" : "qrst", 
    "qwer" : "asdf", 
    "abc:def" : "some value",
}, 
"abc" : "zxcv"
```

}

I am trying to do a search and update the field value for field name abc:def from 'some value' to 'true value' using following:

```
db.content.find({ "abc": "zxcv" }).forEach(
function(ae) {
ae.subdata.abc:def = "true value";
db.content.save(ae);
})
```

I see error "The selection cannot be executed as it contains following errors:
Error at line 3, position 16: :."

Any way to escape the ':' in abc:def?

If I do the same for ae.subdata.qwer the update is made, but not for ae.subdata.abc:def

The colon in the field name cannot be changed at the moment..

Please suggest

Comment: `ae.subdata.abc:def` isn't valid JavaScript syntax. Try: `ae.subdata["abc:def"]`.

Comment: What does this have to do with Adobe Experience Manager? Is this related to AEM Communities?

Comment: @Jens, yes related to communities, trying to update an entry and checking if social:entity could be updated via Mongo for POC purposes